# Contour plot of 2D Numpy array in Python

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, contourf

my aim is to get a contour plot in Python for an (100,100) array imported and created with Fortran.

I imported the array from Fortran in the following way :

x=np.linspace(0.02,10,100),
y=np.linspace(0.47,4,100)

```
f = (np.fromfile(('/path/result.dat'
), dtype=np.float64).reshape((len(x), len(y)), order="F"))
```

So the result is dependent from x and y and gives a value for every combination of x and y.
How can I create a corresponding contour plot? So far what I tried was:

```
X, Y= np.meshgrid(x, y)


plt.contourf(X, Y, f, colors='black')
plt.show()
```

But the resulting contour plot shows values that dont make sense. I also tried imshow() but it did not work. If you could help me, I will be very grateful!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `f = ... .reshape((len(x), len(y), ...))`?

Comment: Yes it should, was a copy mistake, thank you!

Comment: Do the values in `f` look like the values in Matlab?  E.g. could there be data type or ordering issues

Answer (score 0):

The arrangement of `X`,`Y`, and `f` plays a role here. Without looking at how the `result.dat` was generated, though, it is difficult to answer this question. Intuition tells me, the values of `f(x,y)` may not match with the meshgrid.

The improper values might be arising because the values of `X` and `Y` don't correspond to the values of `f`. Try `order = "C"` or `order = "A"`. Also, your `x` and `y` should really be defined before reshaping the data.

```
x=np.linspace(0.02,10,100)
y=np.linspace(0.47,4,100)
f = np.fromfile(('/path/result.dat'), dtype=np.float64).reshape((len(x), len(y)), order="<>")
```

Maybe try [reordering](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/display-numpy-array-in-fortran-order/) `X` and `Y` if this doesn't work.

Comment: Another link that may be helpful

Fortran and C order comaprison: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4940/z400091044d0/index.html#:~:text=Array%20indexing%20and%20order%20differ%20between%20Fortran%20and,There%20are%20two%20usual%20ways%20of%20approaching%20indexing.]